# MATLAB - How to find the peaks in a wav file

Tags: matlab, audio, max, signal-processing

I am trying to find the peaks of my .wav file and have use the findpeaks method

```
a = audioread('FilterNew.wav');
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(a)
```

But when I run the script, it gives me 3 errors

Error using findpeaks
Expected Y to be a vector.

Error in findpeaks>parse_inputs (line 189)
validateattributes(Yin,{'numeric'},{'nonempty','real','vector'},...

Error in findpeaks (line 131)
[y,yIsRow,x,xIsRow,minH,minP,minW,maxW,minD,minT,maxN,sortDir,annotate,refW] ...

I've tried googling but I didn't find any answers so I hope for some assistance here. What's wrong with the code? OR is it that my .wav file is corrupted?!?

Thank You

---

Managed to plot the graphs thanks to mathematician1975.

Now, I am trying to plot the peak graphs and mark the peaks for both the left and right butit is giving me an error of 
Error using plot
Vectors must be the same length

So I checked the size

```
>> size(a(1,:))

ans =

     1     2

>> size(a(:,2))

ans =

      467712           1
```

My Code

```
a = audioread('FilterNew.wav');
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(a(:,1));

[pks2,locs2] = findpeaks(a(:,2));

 figure
 x = (1:length(a));
 plot(x,a,'k');

 figure
 z = (1:length(a));
 plot(z,a,'k');

 hold on
 plot(locs,pks,'go');

 hold on
 plot(locs2,pks2,'ro');
```

[image]

How do I solve it? Thank You once again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Matlab 2015a the output of function audioread() is twofold, a matrix and sampling frequency. Simply typing:

```
a = audioread('filename.wav');
```

should return a matrix of audio samples. Findpeaks() expects a vector so you just need to choose what column of data in the matrix is the one you are interested in:

```
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(a(:,1));
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. I have another issue in the updated question

Comment: @user1730935 typically you should ask a new question rather than update the original. The problem with your plot code is that you made a mistake with the size of a. if you type size(a) you'd get 467712 rows and 2 columns. what is p?

Comment: Sorry I made a typo. It should be pks and pks2. Now it doesnt have the vector length error. But what I want to do now is to plot the graph of the left and right and find the peaks respectively. After that mark them. But seems like I am doing it wrong. Refer to the picture at the question. Thanks